# Redis memory stats. what is the differences between these 3?

Tags: memory, redis, garbage-collection

When you running redis process in the machine, there are `redis-cli`. So that we can get some information of the process.

```
❯ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> info memory
```

and there are 3 things called.
`used_memory_rss` and `used_memory_peak` and `maxmemory`. As far as I know, `used_memory_rss` is actual memory that Redis is consuming. Also I know that once Redis take memory, it doesn't release(free) memory to OS.(They are not doing GC) unless you restart the process.

Then how is it possible that  `used_memory_peak` is bigger than `used_memory_rss`?
and what is `maxmemory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxmemory` is the value of the corresponding configuration directive, it is well-described in [INFO command documentation](https://redis.io/commands/info/) along with the [memory optimization tips](https://redis.io/docs/reference/optimization/memory-optimization/).

Regarding Redis never releasing memory - what makes you think so? The documentation says somewhat different:

> Redis will not always free up (return) memory to the OS when keys are removed... This happens because the underlying allocator can't easily release the memory. For example often most of the removed keys were allocated in the same pages as the other keys that still exist.

"Not always" is not the same as "never" :) Whether it releases memory or not strongly depends on what allocator is being used and what data access patterns you have.

For example, there is MEMORY PURGE command (works only with `jemalloc`) that *can* trigger some memory to be released to OS:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info memory                                                                                                                                                                                          
# Memory                                                                                                                                                                                                             
used_memory:1312328                                                                                                                                                                                                  
used_memory_human:1.25M                                                                                                                                                                                              
used_memory_rss:7118848                                                                                                                                                                                              
used_memory_rss_human:6.79M
...
127.0.0.1:6379> memory purge
OK      
127.0.0.1:6379> info memory
# Memory               
used_memory:1312328    
used_memory_human:1.25M    
used_memory_rss:6041600 
used_memory_rss_human:5.76M
...
```

(note `used_memory_rss` slightly reduced - this means it *can* go below peak usage under certain lucky circumstances)

Comment: so, if `used_memory_peak` is higher than `used_memory_rss`, Can I assume that It actually used more memory before, but some of that memory has been released to the OS. and now It consumes smaller memory space? and thanks for clarify - "Not always" is not the same as "never" :)

Comment: also is it good practice that we run "memory purge" from time to time?

Comment: I don't think calling `memory purge` from time to time is a healthy idea - it can be quite a slow operation.